# Boot Stuck at Starting and Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon Infinite Loop

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

Complete Ubuntu Newbie here. Seems like the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My2GW.jpg) appeared after I updated the NVIDIA driver.

I checked some other posts where it says that uninstalling nvidia-384 using recovery mode would help. I tried to go to [recovery mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyM2v.jpg) then use [root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6NmY.jpg) to remove nvidia-384 but there was [some error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeGke.jpg) that I wasn't sure about.

I don't necessarily need the functionality of the navida card in the ubuntu system and I just want my system to be able to boot...

I think I could be totally missing something here but I'm not sure what it is.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Seems I forgot to turn on write mode lol...Now that I deleted the driver I can boot fine.

Comment: Hey! I got the problem very recently as well... I hope it's possible to use the nvidia driver soon again...

Answer (score 0):

May seems stupid to most of you guys but all I had to do was mount -o remount,r